# Issues Loading Environment Variables using load_dotenv and Configuring SQLAlchemy with Flask using Flask Run

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am developing an API using Flask and SQLAlchemy but am facing difficulties loading environment variables from a .env file when starting the application using the Flask Run command. The application relies on these variables to configure the connection to a SQL Server database using SQLAlchemy.

Here's an overview of my setup:

`main.py`: Here, I load the environment variables using load_dotenv() and configure Flask alongside SQLAlchemy with the database information.

`db_context.py:` In this file, I define the SQLAlchemy configuration, including the database URI built from the environment variables loaded using `load_dotenv()`.

When I run `main.py` file directly using Python (e.g. `python main.py`), everything works perfectly: the environment variables are loaded, and the connection to the database is established without issues. However, when I try to run the application using Flask Run, the environment variables seem to not be loaded correctly, preventing the application from starting.

I tried using `load_dotenv()` at the *beginning* of my main.py file to ensure that the environment variables were loaded before any configuration was done. Here is a snippet of the code to illustrate:

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv(".env")  # I use `load_dotenv` because Flask by default uses `load_dotenv`.

print("SQL_SERVER_HOST: ", os.getenv('SQL_SERVER_HOST', 'SQL_SERVER_HOST value not loaded'))
```

And in the SQLAlchemy configuration (`db_context.py`), I use these variables to construct the database URI:

```py
import urllib.parse
import os

config_mssql = urllib.parse.quote_plus(
    "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
    "SERVER=" + os.getenv('SQL_SERVER_HOST') + ";"
    "DATABASE=" + os.getenv('SQL_SERVER_DATABASE') + ";"
    "UID=" + os.getenv('SQL_SERVER_USER') + ";"
    "PWD=" + os.getenv('SQL_SERVER_PASSWORD') + ";"
    "timeout=3;"
)
```

I was expecting that, when using Flask Run, the environment variables would be loaded in the same way as when executing the script directly, allowing the application to connect to the database correctly. However, this does not happen, and it seems that the environment variables are not loaded, resulting in a failure to connect to the database.

Is there any additional configuration or modification needed to ensure that environment variables are loaded correctly when using Flask Run?